# Ant build fail - because ant forgets property?

Tags: java, ant, build

I am getting the following build error-

```
BUILD FAILED 
C:\eclipse\workspace\ContinuousTesting\build.xml:55:
C:\eclipse\workspace\ContinuousTesting\${lib.dir}
```

Here is the build.properties file:

```
src.dir=./src 
build.dir=./bin 
lib.dir=./lib
```

This is the whole task

```
<target name="compile" depends="properties, create.build.dir, xmlmapping.jar.import" description="Perfom compilation">  
        <!-- Compile the java code -->  
        <echo message="[compile] compiling sources with lib ${lib.dir} to ${build.dir} source dir ${basedir}" />  
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" listfiles="no" debug="true" classpathref="build.classpath" fork="true" memoryInitialSize="128m" memoryMaximumSize="512m" />  
        <antcall target="backup" />  
</target>
```

and it generates the following output

```
compile:  
    [echo] [compile] compiling sources with lib ./lib to ./bin source dir C:\eclipse\workspace\ContinuousTesting  
    [javac] Compiling 42 source files to C:\eclipse\workspace\ContinuousTesting\bin
```

What is my build.classpath I hear you ask....

```
<path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}" />
</path>
```

I am running this through eclipse.

What am I missing?

Thanks!
Azriel

Comment: I can't quite follow this, I think because the error is out of context there.  Are you saying you get a fail in the antcall of target 'backup'?  If so, what does the build.xml for that target look like?

Comment: In which target have you defined the build.classpath?  It may be getting set before your <property file="build.properties"/> is being executed.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the amount of memory given to ant and/or the specific ant task?  Also try increasing the -XX:MaxPermGen value. I've experienced ambiguous errors (java.lang.Error) that were caused by a task running out of memory in large build files.

Comment: Note: this was cross posted to coderanch where the poster was asked to share where line 55 is: http://www.coderanch.com/t/515620/tools/Ant-build-fail-sometimes-cause

Comment: Thanks all for helping. Line 55 is the actuale compile task, which is  the javac call, <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" listfiles="no" debug="true" classpathref="build.classpath" fork="true" memoryInitialSize="128m" memoryMaximumSize="512m" />

Comment: If I clean the project via eclipse - the compile works. Otherwise, if I delete a class file or even entire bin folder manually - it fails. 
The compile task is called from several tasks. In all cases it works fine if I clean the project via eclipse first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is down to the fact that classpath variable is being evaluated prior to the build.properties file being loaded.

This is resolved by not using configurable lib.dir, as it is quite constant.

thanks for your time and help